# htaccess rewrite URL website.com/?collections%5B%5D=Pandemics to website.com/Pandemics

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I'm trying to learn how to rewrite URLs with htaccess but find it terribly complicated.
I have a single page site that displays different content based on a submit form.
I then use the parameter $_GET['collections'][0] to fetch data from a MySQL database and display the database content on the website.

```
http://website.com/?collections%5B%5D=Pandemics
http://website.com/?collections%5B%5D=American+Presidents
```

I want the URLs to look like this when the user submits the form and is redirected:

```
http://website.com/Pandemics
http://website.com/American_Presidents
```

In this case the user has selected Pandemics in the form and information about Pandemics is displayed.

**How do I achieve this?**

I only know that I somehow have to solve it using htaccess and that the syntax looks something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond 
RewriteRule [Pattern] [Substitution] [Flags]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?collections=$1 [L]
```